# Node.js Problems with for(var i = 0

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a little problem. I'm trying to get some data from mySQL with node and when I'm going with a for-loop through the rows I'm getting, I'm always getting 1 index too much or 1 index/row isn't included into my following code.

```
connection.query("SELECT clientid, profileid FROM ts3bot_in", function(err, rows) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Found " + rows.length);
        console.log(rows);

        for (var i = 1; i < (rows.length); i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
```

So what I mean is: When I have 1 row found in my database table, I'm getting i = 0, and i = 1. With 2 rows, im getting i=0, i=1 and i=2.

Hope someone of you can help me.

With best regards, ndslr.

Comment: why are you doing rows.size? Should this not be rows.length?

Comment: Shouldn't `var i = 0; i < rows.length` suffice? Mind the absence of `=` ...

Comment: @Alex Yeah, i just tried .size before and forgot to reversed it to .length again.

Comment: @moonwave99 i also tried i < rows.length, still the same mistake

Comment: What's in `rows`? It should be a simple array, and you should be able to iterate over a simple array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
connection.query("SELECT clientid, profileid FROM ts3bot_in", function(err, rows) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Found " + rows.length);
        console.log(rows);

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that the arrays are zero index based -
The first item will be 0. The second, 1. etc...

`rows[0]` will always be the first item in the array.

Where you are doing `console.log(i)` this will always be 0 for the first item.
If you want it to display 1 for the first item, you'll need to do `console.log(i+1)` - to get over the zero based indexing.

Alternatively, you could try `.forEach`

```
connection.query("SELECT clientid, profileid FROM ts3bot_in", function(err, rows) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Found " + rows.length);
        console.log(rows);

        rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
            console.log(row); // the actual item
            console.log(i); // the index - again, zero based
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: In the for loop solution the row index should start at 0.

Comment: @bluefog sorry, yes... typo! or rather copy/paste error ;-) - have edited

Comment: Your second answer worked fine. Thanks for your help